# extracting ipv4 and ipv6 in powershell

Tags: powershell

ok I'm kind of new to powershell, so I'm doing an simple exercise to extract the ipv4 and v6 from ipconfig command. I'm suing this command

```
$ip = (ipconfig | select-string ipv4) -split ":",2 | select -last 1
```

I can't believe this is so difficult just to grab ipv4 and assign to a var. Does anyone know an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("localhost") | % { $_.IPAddressToString }` yields a collection of all local v4 and v6 IPs.

Comment: What version of Windows and PowerShell are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple oneliner:

```
$ipv4 = ( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where-Object { $_.IPaddress -ne $null } | Where-Object { $_.Description -match 'VirtualBox' } ).IPAddress[0]
$ipv6 = ( Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where-Object { $_.IPaddress -ne $null } | Where-Object { $_.Description -match 'VirtualBox' } ).IPAddress[1]
```

For Windows 8+/Server 2012+, using native commands, local system only as running those commands on remote systems deserves separate answer:

```
$ipv4 = ( Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq 'VirtualBox' } | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' } ).IPAddress[0]
$ipv6 = ( Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq 'VirtualBox' } | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv6' } ).IPAddress[0]
```

Don't use [System.Net.DNS] class:
http://blog.tyang.org/2011/04/15/problem-with-dns-name-resolution-when-using-system-net-dns-class/

P.S. It seems that you use old DOS/CMD 'lets filter some strings from output' approach for Powershell and you mixing cmd tools with Powershell. Both practices are bad but it's another story.

Comment: I know powershell passes objects from one command to another in a pipe, but why manipulation of text is bad practice... ps: comming from linux shell

Comment: If you coming from Linux shell, there is a whole new world awaiting for you. A world without regex for every step, without parsing text files. You have to change the way of thinking and operate on object/properties/methods level instead of manipulating wall of text. The things what you see on the console are just text representation of an object and you have to know what is going under-the-hood to write good scripts.
Manipulation of text is bad practice because output from DOS/CMD commands could change and you script will get wrong data.

Comment: ok, so what is the best way to know what object.properties/methods a given command-let is passing through pipe to another command-let?

Comment: Get-Member command is what you looking for:
Get-Item $env:SystemRoot | Get-Member